# Return React component from mapping an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map } from 'react-feather';

const details = [
  {
    title: 'location',
    icon: <Map />,
    meta: 'foo',
  },
  { title: 'type', icon: <Map />, meta: 'type' },
  { title: 'duration', icon: <Map />, meta: 'duration' },
  { title: 'date', icon: <Map />, meta: 'date' },
  { title: 'time', icon: <Map />, meta: 'time' },
];

const DetailList = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {details.map(item => (
        <li>
          <div>
            <div>{item.icon}</div>
            <div>{item.meta}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default DetailList;
```

Objective:
To map an array and display icon along with other information. However I bumped into error:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

I don't think there is any problem with the `import` from `react-feather`. Because I'm able to use it with `<div><Map /></div>` but not in mapping and render from the array.

Does anyone know what is my problem? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: What specific line is it complaining about? 

Also, do you happen to be using webpack? Looking at the [react-feather package info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-feather) I noticed it warns that with webpack you have to use imports like `import Map from 'react-feather/dist/icons/map'` instead.

Comment: The above code seems correct. However, why are you returning a `<div>` in a `<li>`

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Map } from 'react-feather';

const details = [
  {
    title: 'location',
    icon: Map,
    meta: 'foo',
  },
  { title: 'type', icon: Map, meta: 'type' },
  { title: 'duration', icon: Map, meta: 'duration' },
  { title: 'date', icon: Map, meta: 'date' },
  { title: 'time', icon: Map, meta: 'time' },
];

const DetailList = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {details.map(({ icon, meta }) => (
        <li>
          <div>
            <div><icon /></div>
            <div>{meta}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default DetailList;
```

I'm not sure that JSX handles passing of initialized components particularly well.

Comment: You might wanna mention that this is probably not a good solution.  Also, nice name ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think there is any problem with [...]

Please **make sure** before posting a question. Check if you have `Map` in scope.
**Your component should work**.

btw: in component like this you can map your array of objects to array of React elements once, not on every render of `DetailList`.